# bash get package size with dependencies apt

Tags: bash, package, apt

> how can i get the total sum for all the packages in the loop?
> I guess I must use bc but I'm clueless right now

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(sudo apt install $1 -s 2>/dev/null | grep Inst | awk '{ print $2 }') 
for i in $a; do
    b=$(apt show $i 2>/dev/null | grep Installed-Size | awk '{ print $2 }')  
done
```

Comment: > WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Comment: ^ This. Use dpkg instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `apt` to extract infos about packages in scripts, you can use `dpkg-query`, which has a stable interface, as already mentioned in the comments.

for example you can get *just* the `Installed-Size` of the packages, one per line, an then sum the numbers with `awk`:

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\n' | awk '{ sum += $0 } END { print sum " KB" }'
4650121 KB
```

note, `Installed-Size` will give you:

> an estimate of the total amount of disk space required to install the
> named package. Actual installed size may vary based on block size,
> file system properties, or actions taken by package maintainer
> scripts.
>
> The disk space is given as the integer value of the estimated
> installed size in bytes, divided by 1024 and rounded up.

for more infos about `dpkg-query`: `man dpkg-query`